# Unabel to open another HDD with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs, raid

I'm new to Ubuntu. I have installed Windows 8.1 next to Ubuntu 14.04, on one HDD. This first HDD working fine, I can access to my windows file etc. But I have another HDD named "Maya" where I have just some movies, music..... all dumped there from windows. I need to get to that HDD from Ubuntu too but when I try it I get this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/patrik/Maya: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/patrik/Maya"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: Failed to read last sector (625135615): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I tried to set that disk as shared in Windows but nothing has changed.

Please, before you start with some answers remember I'm copletely new to Linux systems.

Comment: Can you run from Windows `chkdsk /f`? and then try again?